# React validation on blur and on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, onclick, onblur

I have multistep form and I want to make the inputs required. Validation should be on blur and on click button "next". On blur works as expected but I have problems with validating on button click. That way like below, I don't go to next step, no matter if I fill in the fields or not and I don't know how to solve it.

In one file I have:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PersonalDetails from './PersonalDetails';
import CourseDetails from './CourseDetails';

class Form extends Component {
  state = {
    step: 1,
    firstname: '',
    lastname: '',
    isError: {
      firstName: true,
      lastName: true
    },
    errorMessage: {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: ''
    }

  };

  nextStep = () => {
    const { step } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      step: step + 1
    })
  }
  
  handleChange = input => e => {
    this.setState({
      [input]: e.target.value
    })

    if (input === 'firstname') {
      if (this.state.firstname.length >= 1) {
        this.setState({
          isError: {...this.state.isError, firstName: false}
        })
      }
    }

    else if (input === 'lastname') {
      if (this.state.lastname.length >= 1) {
        this.setState({
          isError: {...this.state.isError, lastName: false}
        })
      }
    }
  }

  validateFirstName = () => {
    if (this.state.firstname.length < 2) {
      this.setState({
        errorMessage: {...this.state.errorMessage, firstName: 'Type your first name (at least 2 characters)'},
        isError: {...this.state.isError, firstName: true}
      });
    }
  }

  validateLastName = () => {
    if (this.state.lastname.length < 2) {
      this.setState({
        errorMessage: {...this.state.errorMessage, lastName: 'Type your last name (at least 2 characters)'},
        isError: {...this.state.isError, lastName: true}
      });
    }
  } 

  render() {
    const {
      step,
      firstname,
      lastname,
      errorMessage,
      isError
    } = this.state;
    
    switch(step) {
      case 1: 
        return (
          <PersonalDetails 
            nextStep={this.nextStep}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            firstname={firstname}
            lastname={lastname}
            validateFirstName={this.validateFirstName}
            validateLastName={this.validateLastName}
            errorMessage={errorMessage}
            isError={isError}
          />
        )
      case 2:
        return (
          <CourseDetails />
        )

      default: return null
    }
  }
}

export default Form;
```

and in other file:

```
class PersonalDetails extends Component {
  continue = e => {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    this.props.validateFirstName();
    this.props.validateLastName();
    if (!this.props.isError.firstName && !this.props.isError.lastName) {
      this.props.nextStep();
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { 
      firstname, 
      lastname, 
      handleChange, 
      validateFirstName,
      validateLastName,
      errorMessage,
      isError
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <div>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor='first name'>
              First name
              </label>
              <input type='text' value={firstname} name='first name' onChange={handleChange('firstname')} onBlur={validateFirstName} />
              <p>{isError.firstName && errorMessage.firstName}</p>
            </div>

            <div>
              <label htmlFor='last name'>
              Last name
              </label>
              <input type='text' value={lastname} name='last name' onChange={handleChange('lastname')} onBlur={validateLastName} />
              <p>{isError.lastName && errorMessage.lastName}</p>
            </div>
            
          <div>
            <button onClick={this.continue}>Next</button>
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default PersonalDetails;
```

CourseDetails let's assume it's empty page now:

```
class CourseDetails extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
 
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default CourseDetails;
```

Comment: Odd question, but by looking at the code I have a theory. Try filling the fields properly, and click on the button - it should not work at first, then try clicking it again, does it work then ?

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: Within `PersonalDetails`, at `onChange={handleChange(arg)}`, can you update this to `onChange={() => handleChange(arg)}` and let us know? And within `Form`, you will need to "bind" the `handlChange` to that component for `this` keyword to reference that function correctly...let us know what happens when done.

Comment: Now I can't type anything in inputs. I tried to bind handleChange in constructor and without constructor (handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since React state updates are asynchronous (they are not applied right away), the props won't change right after you perform the validation. The easiest way would be to return the validation result from your validators like this:

```js
validateFirstName = () => {
  if (this.state.firstname.length < 2) {
    this.setState({
      errorMessage: {...this.state.errorMessage, firstName: 'Type your first name (at least 2 characters)'},
      isError: {...this.state.isError, firstName: true}
    });
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

validateLastName = () => {
  if (this.state.lastname.length < 2) {
    this.setState({
      errorMessage: {...this.state.errorMessage, lastName: 'Type your last name (at least 2 characters)'},
      isError: {...this.state.isError, lastName: true}
    });
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

And then you can use it to determine whether you should continue to the next step or not:

```js
continue = e => {
  e.preventDefault(); 
  const isFirstNameValid = this.props.validateFirstName();
  const isLastNameValid = this.props.validateLastName();
  if (isFirstNameValid && isLastNameValid) {
    this.props.nextStep();
  }
}
```

Comment: @maja I like this answer much better. Mine went in a different direction, but this one seems more modular to me.

Comment: Thank you, but there is a problem in both of your solutions. If I don't type anything, just click "next" I get error message only below last name input and it should be below both inputs.

Comment: @maja This is an issue with your validation functions. You should separate the validation state for the first name and last name inputs. In your case the last name validator is overriding the result of the first name validator

Comment: Thank you. I changed isError and errorMessage states for separate isErrorFirstName, isErrorLastName, errorMessageFirstName and errorMessageLastName and now it works :) However I wonder is there some way to do it nicer. I will have also other inputs in this form so if everything is separate, I will have so many states and props in these components. That's why I was trying to do only one state for errors and one for error messages.

Comment: Glad it worked. I guess you could use React state callbacks (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) instead of accessing `this.state` directly in the state update objects. This is just another option to fix the overriding issue: you can either separate error states per input or use callbacks. But the latter option seems like a better practice to me

Answer (score 1):

I would try a different approach. Instead of calling validate functions, and then trying to check for errors right after, I would extract the validation itself, and use it for single responsibility. Take a look at your current code:

```
continue = e => {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    this.props.validateFirstName(); // You set / clear the errors in Form state
    this.props.validateLastName(); // You set / clear the errors in Form state
    if (!this.props.isError.firstName && !this.props.isError.lastName) { // You expect to have that exact state which you've just updated in 2 lines above
      this.props.nextStep();
    }
  }
```

`this.props.isError` will not get immediately updated in your function in which you've just called another 2 functions which update it. That will be noticeable in second call of that function.

Let's try and switch it up like this:

```
continue = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (firstname.length < 2 || lastname.length < 2) {
      this.props.validateFirstName();
      this.props.validateLastName();
    } else {
      this.props.nextStep();
    }
  }
```

This approach would require you to add `firstname` and `lastname` props as well.